# colorWithPatternImage Vs. UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, background-image

Which is better to use if I simply want a background image for a `UIView`? I can accomplish this with either method, but which is more efficient? My hunch is that using a `UIView` with `colorWithPaternImage` is more efficient than using a `UIImageView`. I'll be using this for each row in a `UITableView`. Thanks! Matt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Completely disagree with boreas. There can be significant differences using `colorWithPatternImage` vs other strategies depending on your requirements. For example, if you are using a `UIScrollView`, using `colorWithPatternImage` won't allow the image to scroll. It also generally depends on how large your view is because there is some tradeoff in performance vs memory footprint for different tiling strategies.

Check out [WWDC 2010 session 104](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4088575739) which discusses tiling performance using `CATiledLayer`. This is a good high-performance alternative to using either the built-in `colorWithPatternImage` or `CGContextDrawTiledImage`.

If your requirement is simply to display a single 320x480 static image, then there won't be any significant differences in the various strategies, but if your requirements are more complex then there certainly are.

Comment: What if I don't want the image tiled. I just want it to show up once as it would if I used a `UIImageView`?

Comment: If you don't want the image tiled, you can't use `backgroundColor colorWithPatternImage` unless the view you are setting the background color for is exactly the same size as the image you are setting as the background pattern. In that case, you'll need to add the `UIImageView` as a subview. Simple views are used everywhere in iOS and generally have very little impact on performance. So, there is nothing wrong with having a custom background image for your tableviewcells.

Comment: So, if the view I'm setting the background color for is exactly the same size as the image I'm setting as the background pattern, is it more efficient to use `colorWithPatternImage` rather than a `UIImageView`? Does it make a difference if the image is shown just once on the screen, or if the same or different image is shown in each table view cell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a `UIView` there anyway, so why bothering with another `UIImageView`?