# Setting the background image for the UITableView eats memory and freezes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in AppDelegate I have:

```
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_fon"]];
    backgroundView.frame = self.window.frame;
    [[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

And the app has several tables in simple and slider controllers. Some of this controllers works fine with this background but sometimes when I try to open some the slider with the table - the app freezes and the allocated memory is growing more and more.

Is there the way to set the background for the tables (or for the whole map) without this unwanted behaviour? Thanks

Comment: How big is this image? Is there a reason you can't just set all the backgrounds to [UIColor clearColor] and then have one UIView containing your image, behind all the others?

Comment: `colorWithPatternImage:` has performance issues. Check [Question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043077/ios-using-a-pattern-image-as-a-background-memory-leak) and [Question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093094/colorwithpatternimage-vs-uiimageview) for more information and alternatives.

Comment: The image should be tiled it is 60x60 or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `UIView` to use as the "background".
 This is not only a memory drag, but also not the preferred way to achieve what you want.

I recommend you add the background to each `UITableView`, but your method could work as well, like this:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_fon"]]];
```

Instead of spending memory on creating new objects and adding them to existing ones, this adds the image directly into the `UITableView`s background.

or, you can add the background directly to each UITableView, like so:

```
[TABLEVIEWNAME setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_fon"]]];
```

This should resolve your issue, if it still consists after this I recommend you take a look at the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that is it's VERY resource intensive to stretch / resize images. Depending on what you want, you could:

- Create an image with the desired size
- Create an image and set it as the background of the whole view in your controller and set every UIViews background to [UIColor clearColor].

Answer (score 0):

why not just use UIImageView as your backgroundView, ie:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_fon"]];
```