# UIView background - colorWithPatterOfImage or UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawing, calayer

I'm wondering, what're the differences or, more importantly, what's better for performance - for a very fast redrawing:

1)`myView/myLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];` for about 40 to 90 views/layers

or

**Just using about 40 to 90 UIImageViews** ?

What's better for fast redrawing and what's going under the hood, so I can understand which one to pick?

Thanks

Comment: Better to go with second options. Because colorWithPatternImage will take more time and also It will use more memory as compare to UIImageView.

Comment: What is the source image? Can it be tiled? Surely not all 40 to 90 images are on screen at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This previous post might help: [colorWithPatternImage Vs. UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093094/colorwithpatternimage-vs-uiimageview)

As well as this: http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/colorwithpatternimage-memory-usage/

Consensus seems to be that colorWithPatternImage uses a lot of memory and to use UIImageView.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, CaTiledLayer is the winner for my project. Fortunately 90% of the images can be tiled, for the rest I'll use UIImageViews as there are quite a lot of images (depending on a lot of variables) and drawing them with CaShapeLayer and UIBezierPath would be a performance suicide for sure